# What does "WLAN adapter PCIE config space was not restored" mean?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, airport

My mac (macbook pro 17", mountain lion 10.8.2) is having wireless issues, where it shuts down my wireless connection and I can't bring it up again unless I reboot. The wifi menu bar icon (diamond wifi symbol) does not react to anything I do.

In console the
`WLAN adapter PCIE config space was not restored (stateNumber = 2)`
message appears. 
When searching google, the only hits I get are my own posts on apple discussion and mac rumors. Super User is the last place I can think of to ask and be reasonably sure to get an answer.

At first I thought it was a hardware issue, but under windows (bootcamp) it works and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem under windows.

Also, can I make my wlan adapter **not** restore config space from PCIE?

Comment: you can use this link http://www.redelijkheid.com/blog/2012/12/8/os-x-wireless-connection-problems-solved- ;)

Comment: Tried that, your post was the last solution I tried. The problem still persists, I still would like to know what the above message means. Google didn't result in any answers (at least not meaningful to me)

Comment: ok then i figure  out something else and 1 upvote for your great guestion ;)